could not find `entrypoint` in `solana_program`
I am using Anchor to develop a Rust contract. Why does it throw an error could not find entrypoint in solana_program when I use #[program]? When I run anchor build, I get the same error. However, when I use cargo build-bpf directly, it compiles the .so file correctly.
